# Laravel 9, Google cloud: how to list files?

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

When I execute this code bellow to create a directory it works :

```
Storage::cloud()->makeDirectory('ABC');
```

It creates a directory 'ABC'; But when I try to list the directories using Storage::cloud()->directories() that I created it returns nothing!

```
dd(Storage::cloud()->directories()); // this returns nothing
```

I'm wondering if it's a permission problem because In another directory (Shared drive) it works without any issue!

But at same times if it was a permission problem how it's possible to be capable to create and copy files ?

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: That's not google drive that's google cloud storage.    Either your title and tags are in correct or your code is.   Im not sure what it is your trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I'm just trying to list the directories I've created! I can create but impossible to list these directories.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [Copy and/or Move](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files) with laravel.

```
Storage::cloud()->copy('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');
 
Storage::cloud()->move('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');
```

Edit:

If want to [list the content (files and directories)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#directories) then:

```
$files = Storage::cloud()->files($directory); //returns an array of all of the files in a given directory. 
 
$files = Storage::cloud()->allFiles($directory); // retrieve a list of all files within a given directory including all subdirectories.

$directories = Storage::cloud()->directories($directory); // returns an array of all the directories within a given directory.
 
$directories = Storage::cloud()->allDirectories($directory); //list of all directories within a given directory and all of its subdirectories
```

Comment: I have not problem to copy files or create directories , but the only problem is impossible to list the content (files and directories)

Comment: @mostafa I edited the answer, the `$directory` can be null or string.